# Cannot connect to beagle bone black

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a BeagleBone Black connected over USB and Ethernet. At some point scp (pscp to be precise) did not work anymore but the already estaplished ssh connection was still workin. I restarted the BBB and now I cannot connect over ssh anymore. Looking at the LED's there blinking normaly so I did power up and boot up normally.

I did try ping - no success...

When it is connected over USB I normaly get a message that a new network is connected. But also not this time. I'm not sure if it is an issue of the BBB or my Laptop since I updated quit a lot on my Laptop prior to this failure.

Any suggestions what to do?

OS on Host: Ubuntu
OS on BBB: Angstrom

yours
magu_

Comment: If you have a micro HDMI cable, try to boot up while plugged into a monitor. You could also try putting the angstrom image on an sd card and boot off of that.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly du not have such a caple. I can try to put an image on an SD card and see where this gets me. Do you have any other diagnostic ideas?

Comment: Not right now, I'm actually trying to trouble shoot the same problem. If I get anywhere I'll let you know. (neither of those things have worked for me).

Comment: If you're using [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) on your BBB, try **systemctl** and see what's loaded and what's not. Other managers, such [rc.d](http://www.google.com/search?q=rc.d) also feature the same functionality. So, try to restart your **dhcpd**, **netctl** and other network related services. Look for **dmesg** output, or **journalctl -xn** or whatever else system logger tooling is available to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for trying to help me. As it turned out it was a hardware problem.

I suspect that I had a shitty USB cable, when I plugged in the BBB in an other port. The connection was comming and going and when I used an other cable the problem was solved.

Sorry for not ruling this out first, somehow I didn't think about failing of a static piece.