# Unable to connect beagle bone black by ssh

Tags: ssh, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I wanted to install pip onto beagle bone black,and I tried this:

```
  /usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u pool.ntp.org
    opkg update && opkg install python-pip python-setuptools
```

then, it threw errors,<s>but Unfortunately, I didn't log that errors.</s>
this is the error:

```
Collected errors:
 * parse_from_stream_nomalloc: Excessively long line at 6. Corrupt file?
```

it was occurred a week ago and was't solved yet. 
I wanted to solve it now and I tried connect by ssh,but I failed. 
When I ping to beagle bone, it responds, and Cloud9 IDE is working too but not ssh.
I don't think this is serious problem since I can connect to beagle bone by other methods: Cloud9 or so.
However, to use python on beagle bone, I need to connect by ssh.

Before trying to update and install python-pip, I could connect by ssh.

<s>Do you have any ideas to solve this connection problem?</s>

**Reference:**

[Setting up IO Python Library on BeagleBone Black](http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/installation)

[View Full Version : [VU+ Duo] Error installing ipk on Vu+ Duo](http://www.world-of-satellite.com/archive/index.php/t-31115.html)

**note**

```
I use default OS: Angstrom
I don't use SD card.
HOST PC is mac, OS.X 10.9
```

I checked this but this wasn't helpful
[Cannot connect to beagle bone black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233516/cannot-connect-to-beagle-bone-black)

I could connect by GateOne SSH client, but still unable to connect from terminal.

Comment: is sshd running?  Do you have console access

Comment: yes I guess it's running

Comment: Did those steps help you in using ssh. I too have problem with ssh while gateOne ssh, cloud9IDE and ping works all the time!

Comment: yes it did help!
First, Try these steps from gateOne ssh.
and Before update `opkg`, don't forget updating current time

Comment: Please answer the question yourself in the answer box below. Just write Answer in Question or a recap of the solution, such that the question is marked as solved officially.

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered in the comments and in question edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved this problem by succeeding update `opkg`, so I will write the details:
>
> First, remove `beaglbone` file

```
rm  /var/lib/opkg/lists/beaglebone
```

> and,remove `lists` folder

```
rmdir /var/lib/opkg/lists
```

> then, set current time on beagle

```
/usr/bin/ntpdate -b -s -u pool.ntp.org
```

> afterwards, update and upgrade `opkg`:

```
opkg update and opkg upgrade
```

> now you can use opkg !